# White space around images when using bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Okay, so I'm making a website using Bootstrap 3 framework, and I have an issue.
When I put an image (regular one, with an img tag) it has white space (left and right) across the screen. http://prntscr.com/9wuek5 - you can see that here, it even goes under my navbar. What I want to do is somehow get rid of that white space, and move picture to the center (horizontally and vertically). Here is my code so far:

```
<nav id="mainNavbar" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#colaps">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">ivke11080</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="colaps">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#">Projects</a></li>
                <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#portfolio">About</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<img src="img/chase.jpg"/>
```

I tried to put border around image so i can see if it applies to the white space, but it's not, it's just around image as it should be.

Comment: try adding `display:block;` to your `<img />`

Comment: Tried, nothing happens :/

Comment: could you put your problem in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n9a6kvw3/1/) (or update this one - change img dimensions)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/n9a6kvw3/3/ @font-face 2 times is mistake due to copying

Comment: Like this maybe [this](https://jsfiddle.net/n9a6kvw3/6/)

Comment: Yeah, but still has white space on both sides to the end of the screen, and I need to see background image.

Comment: Yea I realized that after I posted lol. Try this [one](https://jsfiddle.net/n9a6kvw3/6/)

Comment: That's it :D Thank you very much ^^

Comment: Ok I'll post it as an answer for others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can absolutely position your image by using the following styles:

```
img{
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%, 50%);
}
```

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n9a6kvw3/6/)